# algebraic calculations of a complex logarithm

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, logarithms

My math complex analysis book makes this sudden transition, and I am not sure if I can follow the steps to get

$\log_a z={1\over b}$ Ln(z)

given

$z=a^w$= exp(w Ln(a)) =exp(bw),

where Ln(z) = |In(z)| + i Arg(z) is a logarithm of a complex variable.

Can anybody please expand on this?

Comment: What does $b$ represent?

Comment: @MarkViola Hope all is well.

Comment: @copperhat Hi Joe!  How are you?

Comment: @MarkViola Glad you asked! b represents a fixed value of Ln(a). That is,Ln(a) = b = In(a)+2 π i k , where k is some integer. The text says we do that to obtain a single-valued branch of exp(w Ln(a)).

Comment: @MarkViola Like all of us, learning to cope :-).